# Why are they called Chosson/kalla?

Tags: words, wedding

Why are newlyweds referred to as "Chosson" and "kallah" (The Torah already refers to them this way)? the definition Chosson/kalla is Son-in-law/daughter in-law. Wouldnt it seem more understandable for them to be referred to as something like Baal/Eishes- it seems like we are focusing on them becoming Children-in law over them becoming husband & wife? Do any Meforshim discuss this?

Comment: Probably because of the text of the sheva berachot. Which itself is echoing the language of Yirmiyahu 33.

Comment: it looks like the word kallah means both https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.5.1?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%9B%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94%D6%92&with=Lexicon&lang2=en

Comment: Did the word Kallah first mean bride or daughter in law?